# Jquery DataTable loads fine initially, but without formatting/styling when command is sent to change data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

I am using a JQuery datatables plug in within an ASP.NET update panel and it works great when the call to load the table first loads. However, when I call a method to retrieve new data on the table, the formatting/styling is gone. The data is there, but the formatting from the datatable is not.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:GridView ID="tblCalendar" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" Visible="true">
                <RowStyle CssClass="myrow" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="myrow" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

and jquery - I thought I could empty and reload the table but it doesn't work.

```
function reloadTable() {
 $('#tblCalendar').empty();
 var table = $('#tblCalendar').DataTable();
 table.reloadTable();

 $("[id*=tblCalendar]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "dom": 'lBfrtip',
    "order": [[1, "asc"]],
    "buttons": ['excel', 'print', 'pdfHtml5']
 });
}
```

and code behind

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        MethodThatUpdatesMyTable();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "myFunction", "reloadTable();", true);
    }
```

The data on the table is being retrieved from an Outlook Calendar - the button to change the data simply changes the calendar date and it should load the results in the datatable with formatting/styling but it is not. I'm assuming it has something to do when the postback occurs but not sure what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was in fact related to post back and issues with jquery and UpdatePanel. There may be a cleaner way to do it but this works for me.

```
    $(function () {
$("[id*=tblCalendar]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "dom": 'lBfrtip',
    "order": [[1, "asc"]],
    "buttons": ['excel', 'print', 'pdfHtml5']
});
//On UpdatePanel Refresh
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
if (prm != null) {
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
        if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
            $(function () {
                $("[id*=tblCalendar]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "lengthChange": true,
                    "searching": true,
                    "ordering": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "responsive": true,
                    "dom": 'lBfrtip',
                    "order": [[1, "asc"]],
                    "buttons": ['excel', 'print', 'pdfHtml5']
                });
            })
        }
    });
};
```

})